# Iterated Integral not replicable

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

This is from Rudin - "Real and Complex Analysis" p.166, 3rd ed.:

Let $X=Y=[0,1],\mu=\lambda =\text{ Lebesgue measure on }[0,1]$. Choose $\{\delta_n\}$ so that $0=\delta_1<\delta_2<...<\delta_n \rightarrow 1$ and let $g_n$ be a real continuous function with support in $(\delta_n,\delta_{n+1})$ such that $\int_0^1g_n(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Define

$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left [ g_n(x)-g_{n+1}(x)\right ] g_n(y)$.

The Rudin states that

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\mathrm{d}x\int_0^1f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y=1\ne 0=\int_0^1\mathrm{d}y\int_0^1f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x$

which I cannot reproduce. For the left side I get

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1 \left [ g_n(x)-g_{n+1}(x)\right ] \int_0^1 g_n(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1\left [ g_n(x)-g_{n+1}(x)\right ]\,\mathrm{d}x=0$

I have no idea what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,dy=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(g_n(x)-g_{n+1}(x))\int_0^1
g_n(y)\,dy=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(g_n(x)-g_{n+1}(x))=g_1(x).$$
$$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx
=\int_0^1 g_1(x)\,dx=1.$$

Comment: But you need that the series is convergent, otherwise you cannot cancel the terms, right?

Comment: Ah, but it **is** convergent: $\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: I understand, now it is clear. Could you, for the sake of completeness, also compute the other iterated integral (dx first)?

Comment: The problem I have with the other order is, that the series is not uniformly convergent and I cannot interchange integral and sum.

Comment: There's no need to invoke uniform convergence. @EpsilonDelta

Comment: How else can you integrate the sum?

Comment: For any fixed $x$ (or any fixed $y$) it is essentially a **finite** sum, that is all but finitely many terms vanish.

Comment: I think this is the argument that works, I am unsure if the proof in you answer is correct, since you interchanged sum and integral and clearly $g_n(y)$ is not uniformly convergent. You would get the same nevertheless.